# How do you return a blob video in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, html5-video

I have a video saved in Laravel's store, but whatever I try to do to return a video that can be consumed as blob in the fronted is not working.

How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a data URI as the video source. Data URI takes the format of

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64]
```

For example, you want to display a BLOB image, you pass a data URI as the image source:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Image" />
```

So, in your case, if you want to display a blob video on your blade:

```
<video>
    <!-- MP4 Video for example -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,{{$variable->video}}">
</video>
```

Should give you your desired result.

Comment: Interesting; would you know which headers will be needed to give a base_64 encoded response

Comment: @InigoEC you don't need any headers to get a base64 encoded response. You just need to use PHP's `base64_encode()` function to transform a BLOB to base64.